# Using sed to get rid of characters < > ,

Tags: sed

I have a file with lines as follows:

```
...
... <230948203[234]>, ...
... <234[24]>, ...
..
```

I would like to use sed to remove the characters `<` `,` and `>` from every line

I tried using `sed 's/<>,//g'` but it didn't work (it didn't change anything). Do I need to escape these special characters. Is it possible to delete multiple characters using a single `sed` command?

Comment: `bash-3.2$ echo "<230948203[234]>," | tr '<>,' ' '` --> 230948203[234] -- `EDITED Thanks to Paul`

Comment: @srikanthradix: That doesn't remove those characters, is replaces them with spaces.  You want `tr -d '<>,' ''` (as in Chris Down's answer).

Comment: @KeithThompson: `tr -d '<>,'`, without '' in the end, not?

Comment: @userunknown: Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: For my particular application, sed worked where tr was throwing errors. That is likely because I was working inside a Github Action and maybe because I do not fully understand tr!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's|[<>,]||g'
```

With `tr`:

```
tr -d '<>,'
```

Comment: Correct, but I personally find the use of `|` as a delimiter a bit confusing.  `sed 's/[<>]//g'` is a bit easier to read.

Comment: @KeithThompson I use it for practicality. I find myself dealing with literal `|` (and thus having to escape it) much less than I have to deal with literal `/`.

Comment: A fair point.  On the other hand, `|` is also often a meta-character, used for alternation in *some* regexp syntaxes (though `sed` in particular needs `\|` for that).  Personally, if I need to deal with literal `/` characters, I usually use `,` as the delimiter.

Comment: Aside from the personal/specific situations mentioned above, there is one intrinsic syntax difference when using a non-standard delimiter. The first non-/ delimiter must be escaped for **each** *sed range* expression, eg: `printf 'a\nb\nc\n' | sed -n '\|a|,\|b|p'`

Comment: What language/syntax uses pipes instead of slashes?

Answer (score 13):

Try this one: `sed 's/[<>,]//g'`

Comment: What are the vertical bars there for?

Comment: sed 's/[<|>|]/ /g' -- The s does the search; the / is the delimiter; the [] brackets let us search for more than one thing; the | vertical bar is a logical or and the g is to search globally or the whole file.

Comment: You don't need (or, indeed, want) the `|`s within `[]`. use `'s/[<>,]//g'`.

Comment: You don't need a vertical bar.  Anything in the square brackets is searched for as a list.  `sed 's/[<>,]/ /g'` will work exactly was well, except your idea will remove vertical bars as well.

Comment: To add: maybe you want to look into regular expressions, this is one of the easiest example, but already demonstrating the power.

Comment: you are right I just looked back; I get my programming and scripting mixed up.

Comment: @Iman: Please consider editing your answer.

Comment: I thought I did let me try again Thanks @Keith

Comment: This will also remove spaces, which is not desired.

Comment: @Iman: You are nearly there, but as your command appears at the moment, it will **replace** each `[<>,]` with a *space*. To delete the characters, your need to remove the *space* from between the last two delimiters.